# Initial DataGrid Sorting

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a user control that contains a WPF toolkit `DataGrid`. This control is used in many different places in my app. The grid has no knowledge as to the type of data that will show. Is there a way to initially sort the grid by the first column in ascending order no matter what data the grid is populated with? I don't think I can use a `CollectionViewSource` because I don't know the `PropertyName` of the property bound to the first column.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could hook to an event:

```
dataGrid.AutoGeneratedColumns += dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns;
```

and sort the first column:

```
void dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var firstCol = dataGrid.Columns.First();
    firstCol.SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    dataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(firstCol.SortMemberPath, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
```

I would suggest you to create a derived separate `DataGrid` control, placing this logic there and using the new control to avoid repeating the code every time.

```
public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public DynamicDataGrid()
    { ... }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first column now indicates the data is sorted by that column because the sort direction indicator shows on that column but the data still isn't sorted until i actually click on the column.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add SortDescription to the collection, I updated the code, it should work now.

Comment: If the column is not an auto-generated one, you can still use the codes in dataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns right after you set the DataContext for the target DataGrid.