# Datagrid in WPF - 1 column default sorted

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

In a WPF I have an DataGrid with a few columns.

At default, there is 1 I want to make it sort to, but I just cant find how I can do this.

The DataGrid in XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Persons]}" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Score].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Date].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

And the only code behind it is:

```
public ScoreBoard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataSet ds = dweMethods.DecryptAndDeserialize("ScoreData.xml");
    XElement TrackList = XElement.Parse(ds.GetXml());
    LibraryView.DataContext = TrackList;
}
```

What I just can't find is how to make it by default sorted on the "Score" column.

Can anyone help me out pointing me in the right direction ?

Comment: have a look at CollectionViewSource.

Comment: I already tried this: `ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid1.ItemsSource);
 view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
 view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("LastName", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
 view.Refresh();` But that does not seem to work with my above code, i dont know and dont understand what i should do to make it work

Comment: did you consider sorting your TrackList children?

Comment: uuh, well problem is, im only 3 weeks deep into c# at the moment hehe, so i still need to learn stuff too. So maybe i did not set up the datagrid in the right way to be able to use the sorting now ?

Comment: did Darjan's solution work out? Sorting XElement is quite trivial - have a look at XLINQ Sort.

Comment: The above blurb with SortDescriptions should work, but only if the propertyName argument is set to "Name" rather than "LastName". At least, it works for the initial sort... doesn't seem to keep sorting when more items are added.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

> **NOTE:** Using a CollectionViewSource
>   will provide you with more power and control in these situations. 
>   When you're learning WPF I recommend understanding how to use
>   CollectionViewSource to solve this problem along with other collection
>   related problems like **Grouping** and **Filtering**.

EDIT: This may be due to changes in the specification.  This answer is based upon using .NET 4.0, I've not researched whether this solution will work in older versions of the framework.

Given this XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Persons]}" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Score].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Date].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

All you need to do is pick a column and specify a sorting direction for that column.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LibraryView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[Persons]}" IsReadOnly="True" LoadingRow="dg_LoadingRow">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Name].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Score" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Score].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" SortDirection="Ascending" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Path=Element[Date].Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

This will default the sorting to the 2nd column in the ascending direction.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work when the `DataGridTextColumn` uses a `MultiBinding`, even with a `SortMemberPath` set. Clicking the column header will sort it, but `SortDirection` does not.

Comment: @Matt this is likely a case where using a CollectionViewSource is going to yield better results

Comment: AFAICT SortDirection just sets the arrow in the header.

Comment: @fadden There are a number of reasons this could come up. You'd need to show a specific example to make a determination on why the sorting is failing.

Comment: This seems to set the header sorting arrow but not actually sort the underlying collection.  Conversely, setting SortDescriptions on the CVS sorts the collection but has no effect on the header arrows.  What is the possible use case for why I'd want this?  Why must WPF be so asinine?

Comment: @BrianVPS That sounds like your bindings are failing to me.  I'd analyze your bindings and ensure that everything is connected as expected.  Otherwise, there is not enough space in comments to give a more in-depth analysis, I'd suggest opening a question if you've given the problem sufficient analysis.

Answer (score 12):

I described how to sort in code by first of the columns here: [Initial DataGrid Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944822/initial-datagrid-sorting/8946420#8946420)

You could adapt the code to sort by your specific desired column, although the whole approach seems messy.

If you want to do it in XAML ... what may work is setting CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{StaticResource myItemsSource}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="MyPropertyName" Direction="Ascending"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

But I've never tried the latter.

Comment: this link you gave ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944822/initial-datagrid-sorting/8946420#8946420 ) seems indeed to work, but with just 1 downside at the moment. it sorts the first column (at stated in the method) but how can i do it to make it sort the second (or another) ?

Comment: got it now by changing the Columns.First(); to Columns[1];   (thanx!)

Comment: You should mention the namespace required 
`xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it programatically, you can do so like this:

```
 MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataContext.RowItems.OrderBy(p => p.Score).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ICollectionView` in your code behind. 
Assuming you have defined `ObservableCollection<yourPersonClass> Persons` and `Names` is a property of yourPersonClass

```
public ICollectionView View; 
View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons);
View.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
View.Refresh();
```